# I am fetching a lot of names from server , but i want to display only 2 names in my UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    { 
        return  [arrTemptemp count] ;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
     for( int i =0; i<2  ; i++)
        {
          //  arrTemp = [[arrForum objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
           // str1=[[arrForum objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
            arrTemptemp = [[arrForum objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSLog(@"wwww:%@",arrTemptemp);
        }
        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arrTemptemp objectEnumerator];
        NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject];

        NSLog(@"sheetal:%@",item);
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item];
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First change

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  { 
      return  2 ;
  }
```

And If you want to display any two Value on your `UITableView` then 
Here prove simple logic that apply in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[arrForum objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];
       // your can get whatever value from arrForum (YourArray) by change objectAtIndex
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[arrForum objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"title"];
       // your can get whatever value from arrForum (YourArray) by change objectAtIndex
    }
```

**NOTE :** I know `cell.textLabel.text = [[arrForum objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];` is enough but it get only first two value of Array. so i applies above logic that OP can get any two value that he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the number of rows for your `UITableView` as much records you want to show, this will do the trick

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    { 
        return  number_of_records_you_want ;
    }
```